# UserControl объединение

Tags: c#, usercontrol

Я пытаюсь сделать свой контрол в виде стрелки, но пустая область вокруг контрола, перекрывает другие. Пробовал передать в регион созданный `myPath` но тогда пропадает стрелка. Ниже пример контрола со стрелкой.

Как сделать область вокруг прозрачной когда я использую этот контрол на форме?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    base.OnPaint(pevent);
    Graphics graph = pevent.Graphics;
    Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    AdjustableArrowCap cup = new AdjustableArrowCap(System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(2* 2.5)), System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(2* 2.5)));
    #region ArrowCup
    pen1.CustomEndCap = cup;
    pen1.CustomStartCap = cup;
    #endregion
    pen1.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
    GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();

    //graph.DrawLine(pen1, Width / 2, 0, Width / 2, Height);

    Point[] myArray =
    {
        new Point(Width / 2, 0), 
        new Point(Width / 2, Height)
    };

    myPath.AddLines(myArray);

    //Color.Transparent;

    //Region reg = new Region(myPath);
    //reg.Union(new Rectangle(0,0,Width,Height));
    //this.Region = reg;
    //pevent.Graphics.Clip = reg;
    //pevent.Graphics.FillRegion( ,reg);
    //pevent.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Transparent, myPath);
    pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(pen1, myPath);
    //pevent.Graphics.DrawLines(pen1, myArray );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы сейчас в точности повторили свой предыдущий вопрос, заменив квадраты на стрелки, зачем тогда там приняли ответ, раз это не решило вашу проблему?

Comment: Это решило проблему с квадратом, но не со стрелками, т.к. в свойство Region нельзя передать область типа Line или я еще не нашел этого в документации.

Comment: ИМХО, значит в том ответе "костыль", раз он не решает поставленную задачу целиком. И я бы на вашем месте, "добил бы" тот вопрос, который дал бы решение и на этот.

Comment: [Нет прозрачности в Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4464161/12888024). Используйте WPF. XAML не такой страшный, как кажется на первый взгляд.

Comment: [_Windows Forms controls do not support true transparency. The background of a transparent Windows Forms control is painted by its parent._](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-give-your-control-a-transparent-background?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Зачем вы пытаетесь делать это в OnPaint? Задайте регион один раз в конструкторе и всё.